# Cursor blinking

Tags: cursor

I would really appreciate help with my cursor problem.

I have just installed 16.04.2 LTS and the cursor:

(1) is blinking almost all the time (especially when not used),
(2) is disappearing when on application bar (top),
(3) is disappearing when on web browser bookmarks bar,
(4) is invisible a few seconds after opening "Files"(but only when on window bar or folders in first row).

Has anyone experienced something similar?
Best regards,
D.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, the problem can be solved by installing official (not open-source) graphics card drivers. At least on my Asus laptop.